# Document reordering after applying path expression

Tags: xslt, xpath

The following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template name="main">

      <xsl:variable name="a">
         <a/>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:variable name="b">
         <b/>
      </xsl:variable>

      <for-each1>
         <xsl:for-each select="reverse(($a, $b))">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </for-each1>

      <for-each2>
         <xsl:for-each select="reverse(($a, $b))/*">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </for-each2>

   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<for-each1>
   <b/>
   <a/>
</for-each1>
<for-each2>
   <a/>
   <b/>
</for-each2>
```

- Why is the sequence reordered after applying a path expression?
- Is this conformant with the standard? If yes, what section talks about it?

I'm using Saxon 9.6.0.6.

Comment: Actually, that's **not** the result received; you need to change `<xsl:template name="main">` to `<xsl:template match="/">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer from [Michael Kay](http://www.biglist.com/lists/lists.mulberrytech.com/xsl-list/archives/201506/msg00093.html):

> The result of an expression that uses the “/“ operator is sorted into
>   document order.
>
> Document order among nodes in separate trees is
>   implementation-dependent, so $a may come either before or after $b
>   depending on the implementation.

The workaround is to use a `for` mapping:

```
for $n in reverse(($a, $b)) return $n/*
```